# Python Sandbox Runtime

Tags: python, cross-platform, sandbox

I am currently working in a game-environment, written in Python.

One of the desired features is for the users to write his/her own scripts and load them at runtime. The current approach to this problem look something like this:

```
scriptPath = '<ABS_PATH_TO_SCRIPT.py>'
ext_module = None

# Ensure scriptPath directory is in PYTHONPATH
ppath = os.path.dirname(scriptPath)
if not ppath in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(ppath)

# Import module by basename
bname = os.path.basename(scriptPath[:-3])
try:
    if bname in sys.modules:
        ext_module = sys.modules[bname]
        reload(ext_module)
    else:
        ext_module = __import__(bname)
except ImportError:
    print('Unable import file: {}'.format(scriptPath))
except Exception as e:
    print e
```

In addition, there is some logic related to asserting the existence and filetype of `scriptPath`, not included here to the sake of readability.

The imported script would be executed on `__import__`, and expose any defined functions/variables/classes through the variable `ext_module`.

However, the loaded script would be running in the same runtime as the rest of the program, meaning that it has the same system access. For example it might open a socket and execute a TCP-request.

I would like to be able to create a sandbox-environment for this script in order to restrict access and resource usage. From what I read ([PyPi Sandbox Python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/SandboxedPython) and associated links), this might not seem as trivial as one might initially think. I have had a quick look at *chroot* and such, but I need the solution to be compatible withc both Linux and Windows.

There seem to several threads on this already, however none of them seem to address this issue in a satisfying way.

Any thoughts?